# How can I use a ejs view engine with express in netlify?

Tags: javascript, express, netlify

Don't know how to use the ejs view engine with netlify

I've tried to just do `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`, but it didn't work.

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
});

module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

I don't get any output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Express](https://expressjs.com/) is a web framework for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)**

Sites on **[Netlify](https://netlify.com)** are hosted on a CDN (content delivery network) and serve up static websites.

You need to make use of Netlify's Lambda functions to deploy an express app on Netlify.

[Here is an article how to run Express on Netlify functions.](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/13/how-to-run-express.js-apps-with-netlify-functions/)

[Example app - Express + Netlify Functions](https://express-via-functions.netlify.com/) ([GitHub Repository](https://github.com/netlify-labs/netlify-functions-express))

***NOTE:*** During the build process of your site, node is loaded in the build environment and node is available for you to use.

Comment: [@VirgilCane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9251038/virgilcane) Thanks for the edit recommendation. I added some links for examples.